# HTTP Headers for BOSH XMPP, Using Smack on Android

Tags: android, authentication, smack

I'm looking to implement XMPP over BOSH on an Android app using Smack. The BOSH connection manager I need to communicate with requires incoming HTTP requests to have headers on them containing authorization information.

Does anyone have any experience or advice on implementing something like this using Smack? Does Smack BOSH even support appending headers onto the outgoing HTTP requests?

I've spent a good amount of time googling this looking for documentation, references, examples, or anything of the like, and have been unable to find even a mention of appending headers to the outgoing requests.

Thank you for the help!